# DataTable DataSource changes columns Automatically

Tags: c#, datatable

I have DataTable that has columns like in my database table and also plus one more table, when i query data from database it removes the extra column from datatable, I don't want to be like that how can i set my columns fixed in datatable?

Comment: Can you show us some code so that we may see what causes this behavior?

Comment: This is expected since when you fill the datatable/dataset, it fills it exactly as how your underlaying data source is.

Answer (score -1):

You can retrieve data from database with this command:

```
select t.*, null custom_column
from table_name t
```